# Computing maximum and minimum of the norm of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a complex inner product space, $T:V \rightarrow V$ a linear map with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}$. How can you compute $\displaystyle\max_{|y|=1} |T(y)|$ and $\displaystyle\min_{|y|=1} |T(y)|$, i.e. maximum and minimum of norm of $T(y)$ on the unit sphere? 
When $T$ is diagonalizable, using an eigen-basis $B=\{f_1,\cdots,f_n \}$, for $y=(y_1,\cdots,y_n)$ we have $\displaystyle|T(y)|^2=|(y_1\lambda_1,\cdots,y_n\lambda_n)|^2=\sum_{i,j} y_i\bar y_j\lambda_i\bar \lambda_j <f_i,f_j>$ and using lagrange multipliers one can find the maximum and minimum. But what if $T$ is not diagonalizable, is there and easier way? Is there a theorem that help solve this problem?

Comment: This really depends on what $V$ is.

Comment: Whether or not $T$ is diagonalizable, the maximum and minimum are the largest and smallest singular values of $T$.  This is a direct consequence of the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom consider $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. In general the size Jordan block associated to an eigenvalue will influence the value of the maximum.

Comment: @s.harp yes and this is all captured by the singular values

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you, this helps a lot.